# all combinations of differences of two lists

Tags: python, combinatorics

I have two lists, one being the canonical **good** list, and the other being the current **bad** list. I want to try all combinations of deviations of the *bad* list from the **good** list. For example:

```
good = (0,1,2,3)
bad =  (0,10,20,3)
```

after applying operator `op(good, bad)`, I should get back

```
ret = ((0,1,2,3), (0,10,2,3), (0,10,20,3), (0,1,20,3))
```

in any order for the sub list.

The lists I am working with are the output of `stty -g`, which are 36 elements, and the lists differ by 16 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip the good and bad lists, map each resulting tuple to a set and feed that to `itertools.product()`:

```
from itertools import product

for combo in product(*map(set, zip(good, bad))):
    print(combo)
```

Demo:

```
>>> good = (0,1,2,3)
>>> bad =  (0,10,20,3)
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for combo in product(*map(set, zip(good, bad))):
...     print(combo)
... 
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 20, 3)
(0, 10, 2, 3)
(0, 10, 20, 3)
```

This will take *any size* of inputs; not just `good` and `bad`, but you can add in `ugly` as well:

```
>>> ugly =  (1,2,4,3)
>>> for combo in product(*map(set, zip(good, bad, ugly))):
...     print(combo)
... 
(0, 1, 4, 3)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 20, 3)
(0, 10, 4, 3)
(0, 10, 2, 3)
(0, 10, 20, 3)
(0, 2, 4, 3)
(0, 2, 2, 3)
(0, 2, 20, 3)
(1, 1, 4, 3)
(1, 1, 2, 3)
(1, 1, 20, 3)
(1, 10, 4, 3)
(1, 10, 2, 3)
(1, 10, 20, 3)
(1, 2, 4, 3)
(1, 2, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 20, 3)
```

Generalized to a function:

```
def op(*sequences):
    return product(*map(set, zip(*sequences)))

for combo in op(good, bad):
    print(combo)

for combo in op(good, bad, ugly):
    print(combo)
```

Because a `set` is used to produce unique values from each combined set of inputs, the output order is not the same as the order of the inputs. If order is important, you can replace `set` with a [dupe-removing order-preserving function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order) instead:

```
def unique_with_order(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if x not in seen and not seen_add(x)]

def ordered_op(*sequences):
    return product(*map(unique_with_order, zip(*sequences)))
```

which produces output ordered according to the order of the inputs:

```
>>> for combo in ordered_op(good, bad):
...     print(combo)
... 
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 20, 3)
(0, 10, 2, 3)
(0, 10, 20, 3)
>>> for combo in ordered_op(bad, good):
...     print(combo)
... 
(0, 10, 20, 3)
(0, 10, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 20, 3)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the Cartesian product of the good-or-bad value at each index, except that when good and bad have the same value, you only want one of them, not two copies of it.

So, let's zip the two lists, and reduce each component where good==bad to a single value:

```
>>> gb = (([g,b] if g!=b else [g] for (g, b) in zip(good, bad))
```

Then the Cartesian product:

```
>>> ret = itertools.product(*gb)
```

And since you want it as a tuple:

```
>>> ret = tuple(ret)
>>> print ret
((0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 20, 3), (0, 10, 2, 3), (0, 10, 20, 3))
```